# How can I get this SSRS calculation to return the correct division sum

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssrs-2012

I have two separate long calculations in SSRS that are returning numerical values after being converted from HH:MM:SS

The calcualtion are as such:

=count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Invoices") * 10 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "GemPortal") * 10 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "LoadedHeld") * 10 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Provider") * 10 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "AssistanceCase") * 30 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "AssistanceOngoing")* 15 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ClaimPaid")* 27 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ClaimDeclined")* 27 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ExistingClaimPaid")* 27 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ExistingClaimDeclined")* 27 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ClaimPended")* 27 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ExistingClaimPended")* 27 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "General")* 8 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Mads")* 8 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Reassessment") * 28 +count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ReserveReview")* 5 +count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Trigger")* 5 + Sum(Fields!ACD_Calls.Value, "DataSet3") * 6 + Sum(Fields!Extn_Out_Calls.Value, "DataSet3") * 2

Which gives me a value of 6677

And the second calculation is:

=SUM((Fields!Staffed_Time.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!Time_in_Default.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!Time_in_Lunch.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!Time_in_Short_Break.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!ACW_Time.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!Time_in_Coaching.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!Time_in_One_to_One.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!Time_in_Team_Meeting.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!Time_in_Comfort.Value)/60) - SUM(Fields!AUX_10.Value)/60

Which returns a value of 8488

So in a separate text box I would like to divde Calc 1 (6677) over Calc 2 (8488) to give me a return of 0.786

But when I try and do a straight division of these, I'm not getting that result.

I've tried the 1st calc and divided by 1 and it returns 6677 so that part is correct but it seems to fall down when I do the divide.

I have a feeling it may just come down to a set of brackets in the wrong place (or missing) but I can't work out where they should go, that and my memories of BODMAS are letting me down

Any pointers would be much appreciated

**Edit:
This is the sum that i'm currently using - it's just a straight divide of the two calcs

=count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Invoices") * 10 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "GemPortal") * 10 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "LoadedHeld") * 10 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Provider") * 10 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "AssistanceCase") * 30 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "AssistanceOngoing")* 15 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ClaimPaid")* 27 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ClaimDeclined")* 27 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ExistingClaimPaid")* 27 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ExistingClaimDeclined")* 27 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ClaimPended")* 27 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ExistingClaimPended")* 27 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "General")* 8 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Mads")* 8 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Reassessment") * 28 +count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ReserveReview")* 5 +count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Trigger")* 5 + Sum(Fields!ACD_Calls.Value, "DataSet3") * 6 + Sum(Fields!Extn_Out_Calls.Value, "DataSet3") * 2 / SUM((Fields!Staffed_Time.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!Time_in_Default.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!Time_in_Lunch.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!Time_in_Short_Break.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!ACW_Time.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!Time_in_Coaching.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!Time_in_One_to_One.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!Time_in_Team_Meeting.Value)/60) - SUM((Fields!Time_in_Comfort.Value)/60) - SUM(Fields!AUX_10.Value)/60

And it is returning a value of 4158 **

Thanks
Dan

Comment: You will need to provide the formula you are using that is not providing the result you expect - you also need to tell us what the (incorrect) result of that formula is.

Comment: I have now provided the formula and incorrect figure in the main body of text 

Thanks, Dan

Comment: Add a pair brackets around everything before the divide and a pair around everything after the divide. i.e. the only thing not in a bracket is the divide. What happens?

Comment: it returns a value of 1

Comment: but once I change the formatting - it returns 0.79! 

which is exactly what I need. 

Thanks very much, could I just ask that you answer the question so I can get the rep points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a pair brackets around everything before the divide and a pair around everything after the divide. i.e. the only thing not in a bracket is the divide. What happens?

Comment: that what I was missing a set of brackets around the whole long calc for both before and after the divide. 

returns the correct figure now. 

thanks very much!